# How can I access firefox extension resources

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I access firefox extension data from javascript code injected directly to the page?
I´m looking for something similar to `web_accessible_resources` key in manifest.json for chrome extensions.
I´m building bootstraped (restarless) extension with addon-sdk. When I´m injecting individual scripts into the page from content script it works fine, but when I want to access the resource from page it won´t let me - error message is something like

> Access to restricted URI denied.

. I can also access it from url bar. I´m using url format generated like this:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var url = data.url("some-resource.ext");
```

which gives something like `resource://some_long_addon_id/addon_name/path_to_resource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that is not allowed.

Can you specify the type of resource you are trying to read?

If it is a script - you can load the script content into content script, and then add it using script tag by injecting it into DOM of page Script

```
 //content script
 var resourceData = self.data.load(NAME);
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.innerText = resurceData;
 head.appendChild(script);
```

If it is text/xml/html/json - you can pass it using window.postMessage(). 
An example is shown here [a link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-22/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html#Using%20the%20DOM%20postMessage%20API)

You may also find it useful to write a method in Content script that listens for a message event in content script, and on receiving a message in content script from Page Script, you could post back to Page Script using window.postMessage() with the resource data

Comment: OK, thank you. I´m trying to get template file and since it works in chtome I thought there will be something similar for firefox too.