# Angularjs in a Firefox Add-on - accessing extension resources from a content script

Tags: angularjs, firefox-addon

I have been attempting to port an existing Chrome extension to Firefox.
The extension uses a content script to add an element to a page and proceeds to bootstrap the angular app from that element.
This part works as expected, but individual directives that use templateUrl are blocked.  Stepping through the code provides error messages like `Access to restricted URI denied` and `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI`.

In Chrome this problem is solved with the 'web_accessible_resources' whitelist.
This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515055/how-can-i-access-firefox-extension-resources) seems to indicate that there is no analogous way to access extension resources in Firefox.  This would be rather unfortunate, because, although I can inline all of the relevant templates, the extension also includes a number of images which are programmatically inserted on the page.
Is there any way to get at extension resources in an SDK extension?
If not, is it reasonably easy to do so with a legacy extension (as implied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240017/making-content-accessible-on-addon-sdk))?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`self` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/self.html#data) in the SDK to get a resolvable resource URI for files in the `data` directory. If you have your angular file in `./data/`, you can retrieve it via:

```
const self = require('sdk/self');
console.log(self.data.url('angular.js'));
// Prints the url of `./data/angular.js`
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works in main.js or similar (not content scripts).  I use self.options to pass the URIs from main.js to the content scripts, but actually accessing them is not allowed.

Comment: Content scripts are not privileged code -- they do not have the commonjs `require` loader.